# Get email template merged text without sending

Tags: apex, batch, email-template

I need to mass send emails via 3rd party based on standard template in my batch. That is what I'm doing:

1. Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
2. Send standard email and merged body
3. Database.rollback(sp);
4. Callout to third party email service with merged body

I'm getting "uncommitted work pending" error. How can I do that in batch?

Comment: Have you tried collecting all the body values in the `execute` method then calling out in the `finish` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [`Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) method:

> **renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, whoId, whatId, attachmentRetrievalOption)**
>   Renders a text, custom, HTML, or Visualforce email template that exists in the database into an instance of Messaging.SingleEmailMessage. Provides options for including attachment metadata only, attachment metadata and content, or excluding attachments.

I believe it does not count as a DML Statement, so you should be able to call out afterward.

Comment: +1 But it does count against SOQL limits (in case you're using a loop of some sort).

Comment: Yeah easy to control batch size though.